# python function sorting alternating disks

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

sorry for the missing information just now!!

I need some help with my task here, it's basic python programming but I got stuck when implementing the function. Hope someone can help me!! thanks in advance ^^

Task: 
First, I need to build an array, A of 2n alternating '1' and '0'. ie 101010
Then, I need to sort them in the order of all 0s then all 1s ie 000111

To do this, I am required to build a function Arrange_Disks(A,n) to receive the array A and n and return the array after doing the necessary moves of 2n disks. A main function should display the array before and after the arrangement as well as the number of moves needed to do the arrangement. Use values of n in the range of 2 to 10.

Below is the function that I have done so far:

```
A=[]

def Arrange_Disks(A,n):

    moves=0
    for i in xrange(n):
        minn=i
        for j in xrange(i+1,n):
            if A[j]<A[minn]:
                minn=j
        moves+=minn-i       
        A[i],A[minn]=A[minn],A[i]
    return A
    return moves


def main():

    n=input("Please enter a number between 2 to 10: ")

    for disk in range (1,(2*n+1)):
        if (disk%2) != 0:
            A.append("1")
        else:
            A.append("0")
    print "This is the original array: ", A

    Arrange_Disks(A,n)

    print "This is the sorted array: ", A
    print "This is the number of moves required: ", moves

main()
```

Somehow when I run this code, it only shows until here:

```
>Please enter a number between 2 to 10: 3
>This is the original array:  ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
>This is the sorted array:  ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0']
>This is the number of moves required:  0
```

and the output doesn't reflect the number of moves...

So I am wondering if anyone could enlighten me about my code. I know this is a long question, Thanks so much for reading through it and taking your time to answer my question!!

ps I did a bubble sort approach to this question 
and I'm using python 2.7

Much thanks again ^^

Comment: Just a small point, you can have multiple `return` statements in a method; but the way you have written yours, the first one will exit the method, and the second one will never run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then I guess you can use [Selection Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) here:

```
def selection_sort(A,n):
    moves=0
    for i in xrange(n):
        minn=i
        for j in xrange(i+1,n):
            if A[j]<A[minn]:
                minn=j
        moves+=minn-i       
        A[i],A[minn]=A[minn],A[i]
    print moves,A

#examples:
selection_sort(['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0'],6)
selection_sort(['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1'],6)
```

**output:**

```
6 ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1']
1 ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

And to generate those alternating `1`,`0` lists you can use `itertools.cycle`:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> c=cycle(('1','0'))
>>> n=3
>>> [next(c) for _ in xrange(n*2)]
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
```

Working version of your code:

```
def Arrange_Disks(A):
    length=len(A)
    moves=0
    for i in xrange(length):
        minn=i
        for j in xrange(i+1,length):
            if A[j]<A[minn]:
                minn=j
        moves+=minn-i       
        A[i],A[minn]=A[minn],A[i]
    return A,moves                #returns a tuple containing both A and moves


def main():

    n=input("Please enter a number between 2 to 10: ")
    A=[]
    for disk in range (1,(2*n+1)):
        if (disk%2) != 0:
            A.append("1")
        else:
            A.append("0")
    print "This is the original array: ", A

    A,moves=Arrange_Disks(A)

    print "This is the sorted array: ", A
    print "This is the number of moves required: ", moves

main()
```

**output:**

```
Please enter a number between 2 to 10: 3
This is the original array:  ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
This is the sorted array:  ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1']
This is the number of moves required:  6

Please enter a number between 2 to 10: 5
This is the original array:  ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
This is the sorted array:  ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
This is the number of moves required:  15
```

Comment: I'm so sorry with my missing information!! However, selection sort comes out with a pretty weird output like ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0']... but thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @Lavinia the problem is you're passing a wrong value of `n`, `n` passed to ` Arrange_Disks` must be equal to length of list(i.e n*2).
I've added a working version of your code in my solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! I really appreciate it a lot!! But I still don't really get the logic of passing the value of n... like I thought n is just the value that the user requested? Why does it relate to the length of the array in the end?? And thanks so much again for being so patient with my question!!

Comment: @Lavinia well in python there's no need of passing that value as lists already have a `__len__` method, but in languages like `C` you'll have to explicitly pass `n*2` as length. I've fixed my code.

Comment: I understand now!! Thank you so much for your patience and explicit explanation ^^ ohhh erm can I add a question? why did you use moves+=minn-i instead of moves=moves+1? I don't really follow this part...

Comment: @Lavinia `moves+=minn-i` is a shorthand expression for `moves=moves+(minn-i)`.
Why `minn-i`? coz `minn` represents the index of smallest element in the list and `i` is the index where it is going to be moved, so number of moves can be calculated using (`minn-i`), or `2*(minn-i)` if you consider movement of  both `minn` and `i`, as `minn` goes to `i` and `i` goes to `minn`.